# Zend: Invalid Controller error when controller ported from dev to prod -- dev is identical copy of prod !

Tags: zend-framework, migration, controller

I'm starting to run out of ideas -- so this is either deep and mysterious or really really obvious.

My dev site is a 99.9% identical copy of prod. (DB passwords are different).

I've added to the dev site:

```
1 controller in blah/contollers/NewThingController.php  
1 model in blah/models/NewThing.php  
a few new views in blah/views/scripts/newview1.phtml, newview2.phtml etc...
```

All these things work absolutely fine on dev.

FTP'd files to the prod host. Used all the same paths on prod as dev. Changed permissions to match everything else on prod host. Chown'd to the same owner as everything else on prod host.

restarted Apache on prod host.

I keep getting the error:

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (NewThing)
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /var/www/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /var/www/index.php(25): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'NewThing',
  'action' => 'newview1',
  'module' => 'MYMODULENAME',
)
```

Ironically the controller/action/module specifications are exactly correct. And the various bits are all where they are supposed to be.

This is starting to feel like a parallel universe.

I'd be much obliged for any suggestions you might have.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

For them what stumbles upon this page later ...

## !#!@$@%!#@! !!!

It was a difference in how Windows and Linux handle character case in file names, and how that plays hell with the Zend page-loading/routing/dispatching facility on Windows.

Note that the controller file name is NewThingController.php and the class name is MYMODULENAME_NewThingController. (Zend Framework 1.11.1)

I was trying to navigate to a page at the address:

```
http://website/NewThing/actionname
```

This is just fine and dandy on the WindowsXP/Apache install of Zend and works. It fails however on Ubuntu Linux -- and one can assume any other Linux/Unix.

Strictly speaking I don't think is should be OK on Windows, but it is.

On Linux however, this is rejected. Mounted on Linux, Zend insists on the orthodox URL:

```
http://website/new-thing/actionname
```

... at least for the CamelCase controller FileName and ClassName that I am employing.

Now I am going to kick the cat.